# Der Füllausdruck »Weißt du?« – mit oder ohne Fragezeichen?

Tags: spelling, punctuation

Das nächste Beispiel bestimmt, glaube ich, 100-prozentig die Frage:

Sollte man schreiben

> Weißt du? Ich bin noch sehr neugierig auf …

oder ist der Ausdruck so geläufig und kurz genug, dass

> Weißt du, ich bin noch sehr neugierig auf …

reicht?

Comment: Ich würde es nicht als Frage verstehen.

Comment: @chirlu Wie würde man sonst die Reihenfolge der Satzmitglieder erklären?

Comment: Außer (Entscheidungs-)Fragen gibt es noch weitere Fälle, in denen das finite Verb am Anfang steht: bestimmte Ausrufe (_Ist das kalt heute!_), Aufforderungen (_Geh trotzdem raus!_), irreale Wünsche (_Müßte ich doch nicht raus bei der Kälte!_) und uneingeleitete Nebensätze (_Liegen die Temperaturen bei minus zehn Grad oder darunter, wird das Tragen einer Winterjacke empfohlen._). Auch wenn _weißt du_ bzw. _weißt du was_ ursprünglich wohl eine Frage war, ist das heute nicht mehr so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Weißt du, ich bin noch sehr neugierig auf …

Ist die gängige Weise das aufzuschreiben. Als separaten Fragesatz würde man das eher im Fall der betonenderen Form verwenden:

> Weißt du was? Ich bin noch sehr neugierig auf …

Obwohl man auch hier auch nur ein Komma setzen könnte.

Answer (score 1):

Im Duden findet man Beispiele (jedoch ohne Hinweis auf eine Regel) für einen derartigen Gebrauch von „weißt du [was]“, die alle nicht mit einem Fragezeichen, sondern mit einem Komma geschrieben werden.

In Band 2 – *Das Stilwörterbuch* mit der Bedeutung „ich schlage vor“:

> Weißt du was, wir fahren einfach dorthin.

In Band 11 – *Redewendungen* mit der Bedeutung „mir ist Folgendes eingefallen“ oder „ich denke Folgendes“:

> Weißt du was, wir gehen heute mal wieder in den Zoo!
>
> Wissen Sie was, geben Sie mir fünfzig Euro für die kaputte Vase, und wir sind quitt.

Allen Fällen ist die Redewendung nicht wörtlich zu verstehen. Auffällig ist dabei, dass die tatsächliche Bedeutung („ich schlage vor“, „mir ist Folgendes eingefallen“ oder „ich denke Folgendes“) gar keine Frage ist.

Answer (score 1):

Beide Schreibweisen sind völlig korrekt und Standard und entsprechen zwei meist deutlich unterscheidbaren Intonationsmustern. Oft ist aus dem Kontext klar, ob *weißt du* wahrscheinlich als Frage intoniert wird (*du* sehr hoch gesprochen, gefolgt von einer kleinen Sprechpause) oder nicht (*du* tiefer gesprochen als *weißt*), wobei letzteres der häufigere Fall ist. Aber in dem Beispielsatz der Frage ist ohne weiteren Kontext beides gleichermaßen plausibel und deshalb sind da auch a priori beide Schreibweisen gleich richtig.

Comment: Tief und hoch bedeuten hier Ton (wie im Musik, hoch bedeutet hohe Frequenz u.ä. für tief)? Und nicht Lautstärke, oder?